# Why is it telling me to use @string/ where ever i am using android:text="' ? And that it's hardcoded

Tags: android, textview, android-resources, hardcoded

The error says that for hardcoded you must use @string/.. what is wrong with just using "android:text= "price" ??

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="PRICE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A string resource provides text strings for your application with optional text styling and formatting. There are three types of resources that can provide your application with strings:

String
XML resource that provides a single string.
String Array
XML resource that provides an array of strings.
Quantity Strings (Plurals)
XML resource that carries different strings for pluralization.
All strings are capable of applying some styling markup and formatting arguments.

for more information, read it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Also it's better to use a string resource, that way if you have to change the text you change only one variable

So in your res folder there will be another folder called values, and then access the strings.xml file, inside that file you'll put a string resource to use in your app, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">yourAppName</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="price">PRICE</string>



</resources>
```

and then in your xml file, you will change android:text="PRICE" to android:text = "@string/price"

Comment: so what exactly is it that I need to change with my code?